# How to completely remove Fuse for Mac OS X, MacFUSE, NTFS-3G

Tags: macos, ntfs

I want to switch to [Tuxera NTFS](http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/) for better support. But don’t know how to uninstall all these apps before completely switching to Tuxera.

I also install `fuse_wait.pkg` but I am not sure how to unistall `.pkg` file.

I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIjS5jDigwE) for NTFS-3G installation in Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have followed those instructions then you've installed three packages.

**fuse_wait** just replaces a single file of the NTFS-3G install with an updated version. So you don't really need to do anything to uninstall this package; when you remove NTFS-3G it should automatically remove that updated version.

To remove **NTFS-3G** either open the NTFS-3G preference pane and click on the Uninstall button, or run the script at `/System/Library/Filesystems/ntfs-3g.fs/Support/uninstall-ntfs-3g.sh`.

To uninstall **FUSE for OS X** open the FUSE for OS X system preference pane and click the Uninstall button.

If the two preference panes are still there after running both uninstalls, then just right-click on them and select the "Remove ... Preference Pane" option.

And reboot your Mac.

To confirm that the file are gone you could run the following commands in Terminal. Hopefully you shouldn't get any results.

```
 pkgutil --pkgs | grep fuse
 kextstat | grep fuse
```

Comment: when i run "pkgutil --pkgs | grep fuse", i always get the result "com.github.bfleischer.pkg.fuse_wait". How can i solve this?

Comment: @Conbibs `pkgutil --forget com.github.bfleischer.pkg.fuse_wait`

Comment: sudo pkgutil --forget com.github.osxfuse.pkg.PrefPane