# How to completely remove Fuse for Mac OS X NTFS-3G

Tags: filesystem, macos, ntfs

I have problem with the removing of NTFS-3G. [These instructions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/178027/4007) say:

> If you have followed those instructions then you've installed three
>   packages.
>
> fuse_wait just replaces a single file of the NTFS-3G install with an
>   updated version. So you don't really need to do anything to uninstall
>   this package; when you remove NTFS-3G it should automatically remove
>   that updated version.
>
> To remove NTFS-3G either open the NTFS-3G preference pane and click on
>   the Uninstall button, or run the script at
>   /System/Library/Filesystems/ntfs-3g.fs/Support/uninstall-ntfs-3g.sh.
>
> To uninstall FUSE for OS X open the FUSE for OS X system preference
>   pane and click the Uninstall button.
>
> If the two preference panes are still there after running both
>   uninstalls, then just right-click on them and select the "Remove ...
>   Preference Pane" option.
>
> And reboot your Mac.
>
> To confirm that the file are gone you could run the following commands
>   in Terminal. Hopefully you shouldn't get any results.
>
> pkgutil --pkgs | grep fuse  kextstat | grep fuse

But when i run "pkgutil --pkgs | grep fuse", i always get the result "com.github.bfleischer.pkg.fuse_wait". How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a problem.

The `pkgutil` command is just telling you that the **fuse_wait** package has been installed on your Mac. If this is the only result from that command then it means the other fuse packages have been uninstalled, and since the fuse_wait installer only replaces one file in the fuse install that file has likely been removed from your Mac.

Also if you are running the `kextstat | grep fuse` command from the linked answer and getting no results then it further confirms that **fuse** is no longer running as part of your Mac.