# Can't find where macOS FUSE is on my system to uninstall and update it

Tags: software-update, filesystem, macos, catalina

I get this error message every time I login (after recently updated to Catalina).

> The installed version of FUSE is too old for the operating system. Please upgrade your FUSE installation to one that is compatible with the currently running version of macOS.

Can't find it to uninstall it. I've done searches everywhere.

Comment: You could look at this question [How to completely remove Fuse for Mac OS X, MacFUSE, NTFS-3G](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177885/how-to-completely-remove-fuse-for-mac-os-x-macfuse-ntfs-3g).  You can also try copying this command into terminal to remove FUSE core package `sudo  /Library/Filesystems/osxfuse.fs/Contents/Resources/uninstall_osxfuse.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/uninstall_osxfuse.sh` (it will ask your password).  It will say "command not found" if it is not present.

Comment: what do I do if a key lock symbol appears when it asks for password? can't seem to type anything

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that you normally uninstall applications by dragging and dropping their icons to the Trash. In the case with the FUSE software program, you will not find its icon in the Applications folder, as FUSE is a type of extension. You will find its icon in the **System Preferences** window. However, it also consists of numerous user-space libraries and tools, which should be removed as well.

1. Open **System Preferences** and click on the **FUSE** icon.
2. In the window that appears, untick Show Beta Versions to prevent leaving the remaining files of the FUSE preference pane after its deletion. Then, click on the **Remove FUSE** button.
3. Within the **System Preferences**, make a right-click on the FUSE icon and select **Remove “FUSE” Preference Pane**.
4. As you know, every application creates plenty of service files.It is very likely that some types of files were not deleted with the **Remove FUSE** button. Usually, the service files of applications are stored in the user’s Library folder. To get access to this folder, open **Finder** → in the menu bar, click **Go** → **Go to Folder** → in the window that appears, type **~/Library** and click **Go**. Within the user’s Library folder, find and delete unneeded files, related to FUSE in the following directories:

   *~/Library/Caches*
5. Also, I recommend that you check other subfolders in the Library folder. If you find files related to FUSE, remove them to Trash.

   *~/Library/Logs*

   *~/Library/Preferences*

   *~/Library/Application Support*

Comment: Thanks for this, but I don't have a FUSE icon when I open System Preferences. I can't find any reference to FUSE anywhere on the system even when I search for it

Comment: how about the caches and in preferences, did you search everywhere ?

Comment: yes - I think I pressed the icon in 'locations' to safely remove FUSE drive and I can't get it back or find any reference to it anywhere

Comment: do you have any other suggestions please - it's driving me mad!!

Comment: what did you get, when you type the following command in terminal: sshfs -V

Comment: where do I type this? where is terminal?

Comment: Click on Spotlight search on the top right of your Macbook (it is on just on right with your username) and type Terminal, and type the command.

Comment: it says command not found. Am I typing correctly just 'sshfs-V'

Comment: Jennis-iMac-2:~ jenniradford$ run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`
Changing shell for jenniradford.
Password for jenniradford:

Comment: this last comment was what it was asking me to do and now I don't think I can type anything else as there's a password symbol which I don't understand

Comment: I just don't understand whether I've removed FUSE or not and am baffled as to why I can't find it